# Triggering new extra forms in django admin

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin, django-forms

Is there a way to trigger new extra form adding in django inline form?

I mean, when user clicks "Add new inline", I would like to execute some javascript 
code in the meantime.

Cheers, 
Tomek

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You have to use http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){ 
    $("form:first").trigger("submit");
});
```